# Remote vim isn't finding files

Tags: vim, ssh, sftp, scp

Trying to edit files locally to remove the lag and not needing to sync my vim config. I can't figure out why this isn't working at all. If I do

`vim scp://user@host/home/user/project/`

I get

```
:!scp -q 'user@host/home/user/project/' 
'/var/folders/fm/vyvfk53d2b5gf63m7dnv3gqc0000gn/T/vGhn9Hf/0.txt'
"/var/folders/fm/vyvfk53d2b5gf63m7dnv3gqc0000gn/T/vGhn9Hf/0.txt" [New File]
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

If I run just normal SCP commands they download just fine:

```
scp -r user@host:home/user/project/ project/
foo.txt                        100%   20     0.0KB/s   00:00
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify two slashes `//` as [manual](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Editing_remote_files_via_scp_in_vim) describes:

```
vim scp://remoteuser@server.tld//path/to/document
```

So for you use case:

```
vim scp://user@host//home/user/project/
```

but anyway with scp, you need to specify the file you want to edit, not only directory you want to browse through.

For directories, you need to use `sftp`, which has the ability to browse through the directories:

```
vim sftp://user@host//home/user/project/
```

Comment: Ah, yeah i tried double slashes too. So I can't open a directory like local vim at all? Is there _any_ way to do it? Plugin or some other work around?

Comment: You can try `sftp`, which works fine for directories: `vim sftp://user@host//home/user/project/`

Comment: Getting much closer! `vim sftp://user@host//home/user/project/foo.txt` actually opens the file! Yay! However, if I remove `foo.txt` and try just `/project` or `/project/` as the end of the URL it opens the file explorer but shows no files. Is them some trick to that I'm missing?

Comment: just tried on my set up and it works for me well even with folders. You can validate with the `sftp` command directly, if it works for you (for example, if there is not some chroot on your server for `sftp` or some other difference?)

Comment: Well, for a pure sftp call I call `sftp user@host:project/` because `/home/user/` is auto prepended to that URL. However, calling `sftp user@host:project/` works fine and if I do `ls` I can see all the files.

Comment: hmm. weird. And local files you can see? Isn't there some `.gitignore` or different settings in the browser that would make the files "hidden"?

Comment: I don't think so... I downloaded the project from the server and did `vim ./` and I can view all the files. If I ssh into the server and do `vim ./` in the project folder I can also view all the files. So, unless there's some vim sftp settings hiding everything it should be identical :\ I'll keep digging. You got me really far. Thanks!